# Unable to load Aspera Library in Ubuntu

Tags: ibm-cloud, ubuntu-18.04, object-storage

I am trying to load files from on-prem to IBM Cloud Object Store using `Aspera High Speed API`. It works fine in Mac, but when the same code is run on `Ubuntu 18.0.4` it gives following error.

> Failed to load Aspera dynamic library from candidates
>   [libfaspmanager2.so] at location: /root/.aspera/cos-aspera/0.1.163682

With dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.cos-aspera</groupId>
        <artifactId>cos-aspera-linux-64</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.163682</version>
    </dependency>
```

Made sure below env variable is set:

```
a) export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64

b) export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjsig.so
```

Using following java:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_222" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decompile the java code that loads the native lib. (e.g using JAD).

You would find that in:
    com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.aspera.transfer.AsperaLibraryLoader

Here is the method:

```
public static void loadLibrary(File extractedPath, List<String> candidates) {
    for (String lib : candidates) {
        File libPath = new File(extractedPath, lib);
        String absPath = libPath.getAbsolutePath();
        log.debug("Attempting to load dynamic library: " + absPath);
        try {
            System.load(absPath);
            log.info("Loaded dynamic library: " + absPath);
            return;
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            log.debug("Unable to load dynamic library: " + absPath, e);
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load Aspera dynamic library from candidates " + candidates + " at location: " + extractedPath);
}
```

You can try to reproduce the error and get the actual message by compiling:

```
public class TestLoad { public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.load("/root/.aspera/cos-aspera/0.1.163682/libfaspmanager2.so");
}}
```

On windows, similar problem due to missing dependency for the libfaspmanager2.so lib. which are fixed by setting by adding to PATH the folder where missing libs are.

On Linux check dependencies with:

```
ldd /root/.aspera/cos-aspera/0.1.163682/libfaspmanager2.so
```

If there are missing deps, then add folder path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Another note:

The java lib is equipped with  Apache commons logging:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html

So, activate logs, and get better idea.